# Regex searching for patterns in string

Tags: regex

I have file with strings that look like -

```
The end
) [<any text or number>] ON [Sales].[<any text or number>]
)
()
)(
) [something] ON [Sales].[some]
something
something else
something else
```

I need a regex that will find the lines that have ) [any text] ON [Sales].[anything]

The ) and [ and ] are literal characters in the string
I only want lines that have [Sales], if a line has [Foo] i don't want it.

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would match what you are looking for:

```
\) \[.*\] ON \[Sales\]\.\[.*\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gaNnEQ/1)

If you want to guarantee that only an entire line is matched (and not a matching pattern in the middle of a line), you can add `^` to the start of the regex pattern and end with `$`. Just make sure you have the multiline matching flag enabled, which is `/m` at the end of the pattern in Javascript, or adding `re.MULTILINE` as an argument to the matching function in Python.